# How to delete a file in parse.com

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform

how can I delete a file in Parse? I try to delete them through the REST API but it doesn't work.

I always  get this error:

```
"Cannot DELETE /parse/files/appName/e462b99d0e7ed9b98d837493d95c102d_profilePicture.jpg\n"
```

I'm using Parse on a Ubuntu 16.04 system, Parse version is 2.2.23.

Comment: You will need to provide the master key in order to be allowed to delete a file.Note that the name of the file must be the name in the response of the upload operation, rather than the original filename.

Comment: I am using the master key.

Comment: The Note part written in the above comment that also been applied the name of file...................

Comment: which file system adapter is in use?  That should implement 'deleteFile()'.

Comment: You can't delete ParseFiles, they used Jobs to clean files, and that basically was searching for "dangling" files in the database (ParseFiles with no reference) and cleaning them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is for parse server. parse.com shut down 
first remove 'appName' from your link then use this code

```
curl -X DELETE 
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: $appid" 
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: $masterKey"
http://myAPP.herokuapp.com/parse/files/e462b99d0e7ed9b98d837493d95c102d_profilePicture.jpg
```

This is source link 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1411